# Get access to property in custom WebViewPage from OnActionExecuting method ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-action-filter

I have custom WebViewPage and in this class, I have the property which I need initialize from ActionFilter. In this filter I have method OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext). Can I have access to property from my custom WebViewPage?

CustomViewPage

```
public class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public List<IAlert> Alerts { get; set; }
    public override void Execute() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

ActionFilter

```
public class MessageFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { }


    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {//I NEED ACCESS HERE TO ALERTS PROPERTY FROM BASEVIEWPAGE
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{ 
      //I NEED ACCESS HERE TO ALERTS PROPERTY FROM BASEVIEWPAGE

     BaseViewPage obj = new BaseViewPage();
     obj.Alerts // your logic
}
```